# Reflecting Datatable data into class objects C#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, datatable

I am new at using Reflections in C#. I posted a question yesterday about how to reflect data from a data table to class objects. This question was answered and it worked perfectly. My issue now i that i have two classes with objects that needs to be set from 2 different data tables. I have a Sending class and a Statusclass. A Sending can have many Status' so it a One to Many relationship. This is my variables in the Sending class:

```
        private string _Barcode;
        private string _Barcode2;
        private DateTime _PickupDate;
        private string _PickupCustomer;
        private string _PickupName;
        private string _PickupStreet;
        private string _PickupHouseNo;
        private string _PickupPostal;
        private string _PickupCity;
        private string _PickupCountry;

        private DateTime _DeliveryDate;
        private string _DeliveryCustomer;
        private string _DeliveryName;
        private string _DeliveryStreet;
        private string _DeliveryHouseNo;
        private string _DeliveryPostal;
        private string _DeliveryCity;
        private string _DeliveryCountry;

        private int _Coli;
        private double _Weight;
        private double _Volumen;

        private List<StatusHistory> _StatusHistory = new List<StatusHistory>();
```

Each variable has a get and set function.

This is the variables in my Status class:

```
private int _SendingID;
private string _DanxCode;
private string _RecpName;
private int _Logtime;
```

This is my method for reflecting the data from data tables to class objects:

```
  public static IList<Sending> ReflectData<Sending>(DataTable sendingList, DataTable statusList)
        {
            List<Sending> list = Activator.CreateInstance<List<Sending>>();
            Sending sendingInstance = Activator.CreateInstance<Sending>();
            var property = sendingInstance.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            foreach (DataRow dr in sendingList.Rows)
            {
                Sending ins = Activator.CreateInstance<Sending>();
                foreach (var p in property)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        p.SetValue(ins, dr[p.Name], null);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    }
                }
                DataRow[] row = statusList.Select("SendingID = " + dr[0]);
                List<Status> sh = Activator.CreateInstance<List<Status>>();
                foreach (DataRow r in row)
                {
                    Status statusInstance = Activator.CreateInstance<Status>();
                    var porpsh = statusInstance.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                    foreach (var psh in porpsh)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            psh.SetValue(statusInstance, r[psh.Name], null);
                        }
                        catch { }
                    }
                }
                list.Add(ins);
            }
            return list;
        }
```

I need my result to contain a Sending(shipment) with the related 4 status' that belong to the Sending.

the result i get when running this is has no status what so ever but here it is:

```
<ArrayOfSending xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://danx.com/">
<Sending>
<Barcode>SE140</Barcode>
<Barcode2>SE140</Barcode2>
<PickupDate>2014-02-13T00:00:00</PickupDate>
<PickupName>Parts Europe</PickupName>
<PickupStreet>xxxx</PickupStreet>
<PickupHouseNo>1</PickupHouseNo>
<PickupPostal>xxxxx</PickupPostal>
<PickupCity>xxxxx</PickupCity>
<PickupCountry>xxxx</PickupCountry>
<DeliveryDate>2014-03-18T12:00:00</DeliveryDate>
<DeliveryName>Bil AB</DeliveryName>
<DeliveryStreet>zzzzz</DeliveryStreet>
<DeliveryHouseNo>39</DeliveryHouseNo>
<DeliveryPostal>zzzzz</DeliveryPostal>
<DeliveryCity>zzzzz</DeliveryCity>
<DeliveryCountry>zzzzzz</DeliveryCountry>
<Coli>1</Coli>
<Weight>1</Weight>
<Volumen>0.05</Volumen>
<StatusHistory/>
</Sending>
</ArrayOfSending>
```

Hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution for my issue. this is the solution.

```
public static IList<Sending> ReflectData(DataTable sendingList, DataTable statusList)
{
    List<Sending> list = Activator.CreateInstance<List<Sending>>();
    var property = typeof(Sending).GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (DataRow dr in sendingList.Rows)
    {
        Sending sendingInstance = Activator.CreateInstance<Sending>();
        foreach (var p in property)
        {
            try
            {
                p.SetValue(sendingInstance, dr[p.Name], null);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
        DataRow[] row = statusList.Select("SendingID = " + dr[0]);
        foreach (DataRow r in row)
        {
            StatusHistory statusInstance = Activator.CreateInstance<StatusHistory>();
            var porpsh = statusInstance.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            foreach (var psh in porpsh)
            {
                try
                {
                    psh.SetValue(statusInstance, r[psh.Name], null);
                }
                catch { }
            }
            sendingInstance.StatusHistory.Add(statusInstance);
        }
        list.Add(sendingInstance);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: You might want to add checking for Nullable<> types as well, as Property.SetValue will fail if the type is Nullable. I wrote a DataTable to Class and back again class. I also used generics and can build sql scripts from a DataTable. It likes to store object as a DataTable, and convert to whatever object from there. Feel free to copy my code as you wish. [csharpprogramming.tips/2015/01/entity-justworks-class-to-sql.html](http://www.csharpprogramming.tips/2015/01/entity-justworks-class-to-sql.html).